# When should "_set" be added to a Django query?

Tags: django

In the following query, the reference to tweet has a "_set" in prefetch, but not in annotate.
The relationship from user to tweet is many-to-one in both cases as well." How do I determine if "_set" should be added?

```
class User(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    

class Tweet(models.Model)
    user = models.ForeignKey("User")
    favorite = models.IntegerField(default=0)

User.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        "tweet_set",
        query_set=Tweet.objects.order_by('favorite')
    ).annotate(most_favorites=Max("tweet__favorite")) # Why not "tweet_set__favorite"?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have two model, Post and User.

```py
class User(model.model):
    name = CharField()

class Post(model.model)
    title = CharField()
    author = ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

In this one (user) to many (post) relationship scenario, if you want to fetch author of the post, simply through `post.author`.

Reversely, if you want to fetch the posts that written by the user, then you should add `_set` after the model name as an entry point:
`my_articles = user.post_set.all()`

BTW, you can also precisely define the entry point field name in `ForeignKey` Constructor with `related_name` parameter as well, depends on your coding style preference:

```py
class Post(model.model)
    title = CharField()
    author = ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="articles")


# === code ===
my_articles = user.articles.all() 
# fetch with the name defined as related_name
```

ref: [django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) document